# Iterate 3 items in Angular Carousel in a Page as in the example dynamically

Tags: angular

I want to display angular Carousel dynamically showing three items in the page as the example given here https://github.com/lijoos/angular-carousal But all the items are getting displayed in a single page instead of pagination happening as per the example in the link above

I have tried as per the example given in https://github.com/lijoos/angular-carousal

```
<mat-card class="mat-parent">
    <carousel>
        <div class="carousel-inner" align="center" role="listbox">

            <slide>
                <div class="carousel-item" style="display: block; width: 100%;"   >
                    <div class="col-md-4"  *ngFor="let vehicle of vehichleArry;let i = index" >
                        <mat-card class="example-card">
                            <img mat-card-image src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
                            <mat-card-content>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title">{{vehichleArry[i].vehicleType}}</h4>
                                    <p>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
                                        content.
                                    </p>
                                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="navigate(vehicle)">Primary</button>
                                </div>
                            </mat-card-content>
                        </mat-card>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" *ngIf="vehichleArry[i+1]" >
                            <mat-card class="example-card">
                                <img mat-card-image src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
                                <mat-card-content>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">{{vehichleArry[i+1].vehicleType}}</h4>
                                        <p>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
                                            content.
                                        </p>
                                        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="navigate(vehicle)">Primary</button>
                                    </div>
                                </mat-card-content>
                            </mat-card>
                        </div>

                  <div class="col-md-4" *ngIf="vehichleArry[i+2]" >
                        <mat-card class="example-card">
                            <img mat-card-image src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
                            <mat-card-content>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title">{{vehichleArry[i+2].vehicleType}}</h4>
                                    <p>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
                                        content.
                                    </p>
                                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="navigate(vehicle)">Primary</button>
                                </div>
                            </mat-card-content>
                        </mat-card>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </slide>

           </div>
    </carousel>
</mat-card>
```

Expected Result is I have an array of objects which should be shown three at a time in a page whereas the actual results show all the items in the page.

Comment: Do you want to iterate 3 times`(ngFor)`??

Comment: I want the example in the URL to have dynamic values in Angular

Answer (score 0):

Iterated the slide tag and it worked perfectly.